# oracle %rowtype equivalent in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-13

Need to convert the `%rowtype` of oracle to equivalent in postgresql.

My try:

```
create table public.test 
(
    id int,
    name varchar(20)
);


insert into test values (1,'A');
insert into test values (2,'B');
insert into test values (3,'C');
```

Note: I have a variable declare with table `%rowtype` using which we are checking multiple different column condition's as shown below in the example. It's not working in postgres.

```
do 
$$
declare pky public.test%rowtype;
begin
    if pky.id=1
    then 
        raise info 'id:1';
    elsif pky.name = 'B'
    then
        raise info 'name:B';
    else
        raise info 'false';
    end if;
end;
$$;
```

`pky` is a input parameter of function in actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is correctly declared, but you have not assigned any value to it. You can do this with a simple assignment statement

```sql
do 
$$
declare pky public.test;
begin
    pky:= '(11,something)'::public.test;
    raise info '%', pky;
end;
$$;

INFO:  (11,something)
```

or in a query with `into`

```sql
do 
$$
declare pky public.test;
begin
    select *
    into pky
    from public.test
    where id = 1;
    raise info '%', pky;
end;
$$;

INFO:  (1,A)
```

or use it as a loop variable

```sql
do 
$$
declare pky public.test;
begin
    for pky in
        select *
        from public.test
    loop
        raise info '%', pky;
    end loop;
end;
$$;

INFO:  (1,A)
INFO:  (2,B)
INFO:  (3,C)
```

As you can see, the `%rowtype` is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The input parameter can be declared using the table name

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfn(pky public.test) 
...
```

For a column type, use `%type`

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfn(pky_id public.test.id%TYPE) 
...
```